# distinctUntilChanged() not working as expected in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a method that returns an observable as follows

```
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

getUsers(location){
   return this._http.get(`https://someurl?location=${location}`)
          .pipe(
              map((response: any) => response),
              distinctUntilChanged()
           )
}
```

(Please assume all the required dependencies are imported)

So in order to display the result of users, I call loadUsers method.

```
loadUsers(location){
   this.getUsers(location).subscribe( users => {
       this.userList = users;
    });
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.loadUsers('mumbai');
}
```

So the above code loads the list of users for me, for all the users who have location Mumbai.

Now I have a list of locations on the UI with the checkbox next to it like

```
Mumbai,
Delhi,
Kerala
```

So clicking on one location will call the loadUsers method with the location name as a parameter.

So when I click on Mumbai again from the checkbox ( before clicking on any other checkbox other than Mumbai) I do not want to loadUsers belonging to Mumbai again as it was already loaded on load.

I have read that distinctUntilChanged()  can be used in such cases. However it doesn't seem to work for me as when I select Mumbai from the checkbox list, it still hits a call to loadUsers from Mumbai

PS - This is not the real use case. The above description is just an attempt to get my problem clear to you all.

I am a newbie into Angular and Rxjs. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

your `distinctUntilChanged` is applied to the response `this._http.get()` returns. If you want to prevent invoking `getUsers()` again for the same location you would have to rewrite your code a bit to have your list of locations be observable // push a `next` location into a Subject so you can use `distinctUntilChanged` on this input list.

```
const currentLocation = new Subject();
on('click', () => currentLocation.next(this.value)); // on your location list items checkboxes

currentLocation.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  mergeMap(location => loadUsers(location)
)
.subscribe(users => {
  this.userList = users;
});
```

I have left out a lot of boilerplate with regards to angular but i hope you get the gist of what the solution should be.

Comment: Thanks Mark.I will give it a try.